# R how to extract specific elements in a data frame consisting of character lists

Tags: r

I have a data frame `labels` consisting of 3 rows of 1 column like this:

```
 labels
                  labels(n)
 1 Text, Commission20120125
 2    Text, Council2015mmdd
 3 Text, Parliament20140312
```

with:

```
 labels[1,]
 [[1]]
 [1] "Text"               "Commission20120125"
```

and:

```
  labels[2,]
  [[1]]
 [1] "Text"            "Council2015mmdd"
```

and:

```
 labels[3,]
 [[1]]
 [1] "Text"               "Parliament20140312"
```

Is there any "simple" way to access everything but `"Text"` and put it in a vector, like this:

```
c("Commission20120125", "Council2015mmdd", "Parliament20140312")
```

As my only solution so far is to manually do:

```
l1 <- as.vector(labels[1,])  
l1 <- unlist(l1)  
l1 <- str_extract(l1, "[A-Z][a-z]+[0-9]+")
l <- l1[2]
```

and so on for every raw.

Comment: Can you post the `dput` output of labels example. Try `sapply(labels[,1], '[',2)`

Comment: Here it is: `structure(list(labels(n) = list(c("Text", "Commission20120125"
), c("Text", "Council2015mmdd"), c("Text", "Parliament20140312"
))), .Names = "labels(n)", row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")`

Comment: @akrun Can you please give me some explanations about how `sapply(labels[,1], '[',2)` works, because I can't figure it out myself. Thanks.

Comment: It is extracting the 2nd element from each of list elements.  More details can be found at `?Extract`.  `labels[,1]` is a list with 3 list elements.  We use `lapply/sapply` to loop over the list and then subset the 2nd element from each of the list elements.

Comment: @akrun Thanks. I suppose the `2` is for the second element of the list, but what `[` is for, please?

Comment: It is similar to the code `sapply(labels[,1], function(x) x[2])` without the anonymous function call.  The `[` will subset the 2nd element from each of the list elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try

```
sapply(labels[,1], '[',2)
#[1] "Commission20120125" "Council2015mmdd"    "Parliament20140312"
```

#### data

```
labels <- data.frame(labelsn = I(list(c('Text', 'Commission20120125'),
 c('Text', 'Council2015mmdd'), c('Text', 'Parliament20140312'))))
```

Comment: @agstudy Thanks, I am not sure whether this is the structure of the OP's dataset.

Answer (score 1):

Another option (I think it is faster),

```
unlist(labels)[c(FALSE,TRUE)] ## use of recycling here 

      labelsn2             labelsn4             labelsn6 
"Commission20120125"    "Council2015mmdd" "Parliament20140312"
```

Comment: thanks for your help. Your solution shows me an other way I will try to understand too.

Comment: I have figured out how to remove the names of the columns to get what I want: `unlist(labels, use.names = FALSE)[c(FALSE,TRUE)]`. Thanks for your help.